# How change default color of text in wxRitchTextCtrl

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

How change color default of text?
wxRitchTextCtrl

Here is my [Source code](http://gist.github.com/anonymous/2a8a56e01b47b994fe5a)
I change foreground color, Default color etc. always i get black color.

```
ed = new wxRichTextCtrl(panel, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString, ..., wxVSCROLL);
ed->SetBackgroundColour(wxColour(0, 121, 122));
ed->SetForegroundColour(wxColour(255, 255, 255));
```

Comment: Please don't paste links to source code.  Paste the *parts* of your code you are having issues with.  Also supplement with compiler messages and the actual versus expected output of what you have tried.  Better support will come if you append the results from using a debugger.

Comment: All parts are important in this sample. this is a trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try this:

```
wxRichTextAttr attr = ed->GetBasicStyle();
attr.SetBackgroundColour(wxColour(0, 121, 122));
attr.SetTextColour(wxColour(255, 255, 255));
ed->SetBasicStyle(attr);
```

According to the docs, `GetBasicStyle()` and `SetBasicStyle()` refer to 'the style of the whole buffer before further styles are applied'. Constructing a copy of the current basic style as a baseline ensures we only change the attributes we want and don't inadvertently change any other defaults.